# UI Bug During Review

Tags: bug, review

(all annotations in red are mine)

[image: Bug]

While reviewing, a random black bar appears across the question that I'm viewing. This appears on every post I review, only in the Close Votes category.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: @gnat Ugh, sorry I didn't see that. Yeah, it's a dupe.